# PHP code not returning correct MySQL result

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, hosted

I'm querying a set of data from MySQL on a hosted server. When I did it on my local machine, it worked fine, but on the hosted server, it's not returning anything. The weird thing is, when I use this GUI for the hosted environment to run the same query, it does return the results.

So here are some codes, etc.

This is index.php:

```
<?php

$servername = "username.db.theservername.ether.com";
$mysqllogin = "username";
$mysqlpassword = "thepassword";
$dbName = "StepsMath";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $mysqllogin, $mysqlpassword, $dbName);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die ("connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    echo "connection failed.";
}

$set_name = 'test_set';
$query = "select word, definition from word_list where set_name = '$set_name'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$conn->close();
             // *********************************************
echo $query; // <-------- *******this prints the query*******
             // *********************************************
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<title>this is a title</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var json = '<?= json_encode($result) ?>';
    var word_list = JSON.parse(json);
    console.log(word_list);     //line 24
    console.log(json);          //line 25
    function getUserId(){
        return '<?= $user_id ?>';
    }
    if(!getUserId()) window.location = 'login.html';
</script>
</head>
<body>body stuff</body>
</html>
```

Table word_list only has three columns: word, definition, and set_name

The above code is supposed to return rows of words and definitions. Instead, as I check in the browser console, it returns the following:

```
{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}
```

This is the query that runs:

```
select word, definition from word_list where set_name = 'test_set'
```

If I copy that exact query and run it in the MySQL GUI in the hosted server,

[image: GUI MySQL environment provided by GoDaddy]

the following is returned:

[image: Result of running the same query in GUI]

So to summarize the question, why is there a discrepancy in the result between the GUI and the code??

Comment: Do you use the same passwords for both local and remote databases?

Comment: you forgot to loop through your resluts

Comment: Also the databases on your local and remote box are different.  In your GUI it shows StepsMath, whereas in your code it shows vocab_builder

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond : Oops. They're not the same.

Comment: @CodeGodie: there are no results to loop through. The object that's returned doesn't have anything in it. Everything is Null.

Comment: Make sure you set the correct db otherwise you just get an error with the query where it fails and returns null for those values.

Comment: Oh and don't close the connection until after you retrieve the results

Comment: btw. the line after `die()` won't be executed ever.

Comment: you didn't enable exceptions, so mysqli is going to simply return boolean false on failure. Since you don't check for that false, you're just assuming nothing could ever go wrong.

Comment: @MarcB I'll be sure to add that in later. But right now, I'm sure that it doesn't return false. It returns an object, and it's saying that there are no rows to return.

Comment: if num_rows says there's 0 rows, then the query matched nothing...

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond thanks for bunch of pointers. I confused the local version with the live version, so that's why there were mistakes. I made sure the connection isn't closed until the results are retrieved, but it still has the same problem.

Comment: @MarcB That's the perplexing part. When I run the exact same query on the GUI, it does return rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this line:

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

to this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res[] = $row;
}
var_dump($res);
```

The information you previously got: `{"current_field":null,"field_count":null,"lengths":null,"num_rows":null,"type":null}` are all `mysqli_result` properties.

Read this, it will help you uderstand what you did wrong:http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php